# Is it possible to create a new AdSense account for a subdomain when the root domain is already approved for AdSense?

Tags: subdomain, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I have a domain (`example.com`) that is AdSense approved, but I want to create a subdomain (`abc.example.com`) which I would want to use another AdSense account with. How possible is this?